# UnicodeEncodeError for Google App Engine Datastore to BigQuery process

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to follow along with [this Codelab](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/datastoretobigquery) that shows you how to take data from your Google App Engine Datastore and move it through Google Cloud Storage and on to BigQuery by setting up a MapReduce pipeline. I set up a Google App Engine Datastore entity and have a process to collect tweets about certain stocks that I want to collect data on just as a test. I believe I've followed everything as was outlined in the example, but the shards that do all the work of breaking up the data and loading it into Cloud Storage are raising UnicodeEncodeErrors. Here's the log from where I tested the app on the dev app server:

```
INFO     2012-12-18 20:41:07,645 dev_appserver.py:3103] "POST /mapreduce/worker_callback HTTP/1.1" 500 -
WARNING  2012-12-18 20:41:07,648 taskqueue_stub.py:1981] Task appengine-mrshard-1582400592541472B07B9-0-0 failed to execute. This task will retry in 0.100 seconds
ERROR    2012-12-18 20:41:09,453 webapp2.py:1552] 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 80: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Tank\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\jibdantest-bq\mapreduce\base_handler.py", line 65, in post
self.handle()
File "C:\Users\Tank\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\jibdantest-bq\mapreduce\handlers.py", line 181, in handle
entity, input_reader, ctx, tstate)
File "C:\Users\Tank\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\jibdantest-bq\mapreduce\handlers.py", line 298, in process_data
output_writer.write(output, ctx)
File "C:\Users\Tank\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\jibdantest-bq\mapreduce\output_writers.py", line 659, in write
ctx.get_pool("file_pool").append(self._filename, str(data))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 80: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here's the code:

```
import json
import webapp2
import urllib2
import time
import calendar
import datetime
import httplib2

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

from mapreduce.lib import files
from mapreduce import base_handler
from mapreduce import mapreduce_pipeline
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials

SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'
PROJECT_ID = 'project_id' # Your Project ID here
BQ_DATASET_ID = 'datastore_data'
GS_BUCKET = 'bucketname'
ENTITY_KIND = 'main.streamdata'

class streamdata(db.Model):
    querydate = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    ticker = db.StringProperty()
    created_at = db.StringProperty()
    tweet_id = db.StringProperty()
    text = db.TextProperty()
    source = db.StringProperty()

class DatastoreMapperPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase):

    def run(self, entity_type):

        output = yield mapreduce_pipeline.MapperPipeline(
          "Datastore Mapper %s" % entity_type,
          "main.datastore_map",
          "mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader",
          output_writer_spec="mapreduce.output_writers.FileOutputWriter",
          params={
              "input_reader":{
                  "entity_kind": entity_type,
                  },
              "output_writer":{
                  "filesystem": "gs",
                  "gs_bucket_name": GS_BUCKET,
                  "output_sharding":"none",
                  }
              },
              shards=10)

        yield CloudStorageToBigQuery(output)

class CloudStorageToBigQuery(base_handler.PipelineBase):

    def run(self, csv_output):

        credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=SCOPE)
        http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        bigquery_service = build("bigquery", "v2", http=http)

        jobs = bigquery_service.jobs()
        table_name = 'datastore_data_%s' % datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime(
            '%m%d%Y_%H%M%S')
        files = [str(f.replace('/gs/', 'gs://')) for f in csv_output]
        result = jobs.insert(projectId=PROJECT_ID,
                            body=build_job_data(table_name,files))

        result.execute()

def build_job_data(table_name, files):
  return {"projectId": PROJECT_ID,
          "configuration":{
              "load": {
                  "sourceUris": files,
                  "schema":{
                      "fields":[
                          {
                              "name":"querydate",
                              "type":"INTEGER",
                          },
                          {
                              "name":"ticker",
                              "type":"STRING",
                          },
                          {
                              "name":"created_at",
                              "type":"STRING",
                          },
                          {
                              "name":"tweet_id",
                              "type":"STRING",
                          },
                          {   "name":"text",
                              "type":"TEXT",
                          },
                          {    
                              "name":"source",
                              "type":"STRING",
                          }
                          ]
                      },
                  "destinationTable":{
                      "projectId": PROJECT_ID,
                      "datasetId": BQ_DATASET_ID,
                      "tableId": table_name,
                      },
                  "maxBadRecords": 0,
                  }
              }
          }

def datastore_map(entity_type):
    data = db.to_dict(entity_type)
    resultlist = [timestamp_to_posix(data.get('querydate')),
                    data.get('ticker'),
                    data.get('created_at'),
                    data.get('tweet_id'),
                    data.get('text'),
                    data.get('source')]
    result = ','.join(['"%s"' % field for field in resultlist])
    yield("%s\n" % result)

def timestamp_to_posix(timestamp):
    return int(time.mktime(timestamp.timetuple()))

class DatastoretoBigQueryStart(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        pipeline = DatastoreMapperPipeline(ENTITY_KIND)
        pipeline.start()
        path = pipeline.base_path + "/status?root=" + pipeline.pipeline_id
        self.redirect(path)

class StreamHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        tickers = ['AAPL','GOOG', 'IBM', 'BAC', 'INTC',
                   'DELL', 'C', 'JPM', 'WFM', 'WMT', 
                   'AMZN', 'HOT', 'SPG', 'SWY', 'HTSI', 
                   'DUK', 'CEG', 'XOM', 'F', 'WFC', 
                   'CSCO', 'UAL', 'LUV', 'DAL', 'COST', 'YUM',
                   'TLT', 'HYG', 'JNK', 'LQD', 'MSFT',
                   'GE', 'LVS', 'MGM', 'TWX', 'DIS', 'CMCSA',
                   'TWC', 'ORCL', 'WPO', 'NYT', 'GM', 'JCP', 
                   'LNKD', 'OPEN', 'NFLX', 'SBUX', 'GMCR', 
                   'SPLS', 'BBY', 'BBBY', 'YHOO', 'MAR', 
                   'L', 'LOW', 'HD', 'HOV', 'TOL', 'NVR', 'RYL', 
                   'GIS', 'K', 'POST', 'KRFT', 'CHK', 'GGP', 
                   'RSE', 'RWT', 'AIG', 'CB', 'BRK.A', 'CAT']

        for i in set(tickers):

            url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='
            resultcount = '&rpp=100'
            language = '&lang=en'
            encoding = '%40%24'
            tickerstring = url + encoding + i + resultcount + language
            tickurl = urllib2.Request(tickerstring)
            tweets = urllib2.urlopen(tickurl)
            code = tweets.getcode()

            if code == 200:
                results = json.load(tweets, 'utf-8')
                if "results" in results:
                    entries = results["results"]
                    for entry in entries:
                        tweet = streamdata()
                        created = entry['created_at']
                        tweetid = entry['id_str']
                        tweettxt = entry['text']
                        tweet.ticker = i
                        tweet.created_at = created
                        tweet.tweet_id = tweetid
                        tweet.text = tweettxt
                        tweet.source = "Twitter"
                        tweet.put()

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('<a href="/start">Click here</a> to start the Datastore to BigQuery pipeline. ')
        self.response.out.write('<a href="/add_data">Click here</a> to start adding data to the datastore. ')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                               ('/', MainHandler),
                               ('/start', DatastoretoBigQueryStart), 
                               ('/add_data', StreamHandler)], 
                              debug=True)
```

Any insights anyone may have would be a big help.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are converting Unicode data to a bytestring:

```
ctx.get_pool("file_pool").append(self._filename, str(data))
```

When you do that without specifying an encoding, Python falls back to the default, which is ASCII. You'll need to settle on a different encoding instead, one that can handle all Unicode codepoints your data contains.

For most text, UTF-8 is a good choice for that; if you have a lot of non-western text (Arabic, Asian, etc.) then UTF-16 might be more efficient. In either case, you'll have to explicitly encode:

```
ctx.get_pool("file_pool").append(self._filename, data.encode('utf8'))
```

When reading back the data from that file, use `filedata.decode('utf8')` to decode back to Unicode.

See the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for more information on Python and Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

```
ctx.get_pool("file_pool").append(self._filename, str(data))
```

if data contains unicode characters, this will fail. Try

```
ctx.get_pool("file_pool").append(self._filename, unicode(data))
```