# HttpError 401 Trying to access a BigQuery url via CloudStorage Pipeline

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

This question is essentially a follow-on from my previous question you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941416/unicodeencodeerror-for-google-app-engine-datastore-to-bigquery-process). After taking care of the encoding error I encountered, I ran into a new HttpError 401 issue. The trace from my dev app server log is below:

```
ERROR    2012-12-20 03:10:46,312 pipeline.py:2237] Generator main.CloudStorageToBigQuery(*([u'/gs/jibdancsvtest/Datastore Mapper main.streamdata-1582389642294FE5DBBCE-output'],), **{})#2d3dba4f4a5211e2bf0ac3cee1488e47 raised exception. HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/1093XXXXXXXXX/jobs?alt=json returned "Invalid Credentials">
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tank\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\jibdantest-bq\mapreduce\lib\pipeline\pipeline.py", line 2030, in evaluate
    self, pipeline_key, root_pipeline_key, caller_output)
  File "C:\Users\Tank\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\jibdantest-bq\mapreduce\lib\pipeline\pipeline.py", line 1064, in _run_internal
    return self.run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tank\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\jibdantest-bq\main.py", line 77, in run
    result.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Tank\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\jibdantest-bq\oauth2client\util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tank\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\jibdantest-bq\apiclient\http.py", line 678, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/1093XXXXXXXXX/jobs?alt=json returned "Invalid Credentials">
```

I also thought I'd post the json response from the url. Here is that json:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

If you follow the link to my previous question here on stackoverflow, you'll find the code in my main.py file that runs everything. But if I need to repost it here I can do that.

So, I'm thinking it's an OAuth issue, but I believe I have all of that set up properly. Any suggestions for other things I can do/investigate would be great.

Many Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

When you run on the local dev server, you need to set your credentials differently:

First, you need to setup a local credentials store. Use get_refresh_token.py from here: https://codereview.appspot.com/5362041/diff/1/samples/oauth2cmdline/get_refresh_token.py

Setup a Client ID for web applications on your Google API Console and pass in the parameters to the script above (will launch into a browser for OAuth2 authentication). This will create a local file with credentials you can then pass to your API Client for authenticated requests:

```
from oauth2client.client import Storage, Credentials
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials

class FileStorage(Storage):
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self._filepath = filepath

    def locked_get(self):
        with open(self._filepath, 'r') as f:
            json = f.read()
        credentials = Credentials.new_from_json(json)
        return credentials

if not os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Development'):
    credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')
else:
    filepath = #Path to credentials file here
    storage = FileStorage(filepath)
    credentials = storage.get()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks. I hadn't seen this workaround for working with credentials on the local dev server before. I had just assumed I needed to upload my code to production and essentially test in the prod environment. I'll definitely give this a try and let you know where I get.

Comment: I use this method to develop with so I can assure you it works when interacting with BigQuery. However, you will not be able to write out to Google Storage as of now. If you already have data in Google Storage and want BigQuery to interact with that, you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check if you have correct permission to run the job. We ran into similar problem and found out that we needed Owner permission to run the jobs.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but still got the same issue. But it did give me some ideas to look at between how GAE, Cloud Storage and BigQuery work together. Hopefully I can report later that I was able to answer my own question :)